# Update CSV File Without Re-Writing

Tags: python, csv, file

Is there a more efficient way to update a row in a csv file without previously having stored all the data? The code below works, but I don't want to have to store the entire file's data.

```
with open("users.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    csv_rows = list(csv.reader(file))

    # Dictionary with username : password
    users = {row[1]: row[2] for row in csv_rows}
    

def increment_login_count(username: str) -> int:
    """
    Updates a user's login count (in the csv file and list)
    and returns the new value
    
    Arguments:
        username (str): The user whose count should be updated
    
    Returns:
        login_count (int)
    """
    
    login_count = 0
    for index, row in enumerate(csv_rows):
        if row[1] == username:
            login_count = int(row[4]) + 1
            csv_rows[index][4] = login_count
            
            with open("users.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                
                for row in csv_rows:
                    writer.writerow(row)
            
    return login_count
```

Comment: There are 5 columns in the csv file:
ID,USERNAME,PASSWORD,REGISTRATION_TIMESTAMP,LOGIN_COUNT

Comment: Unless you want to add new rows at the end, there's no way to update without reading and rewriting. Files don't provide any way to insert or replace in the middle, unless the replacement is the same length as the original.

Comment: In this case the replacement row has the same amount of columns as the previous. Do you mean in terms of the character length of the row?

Comment: Yes, it has to be the same number of characters. There's no way to push over the other lines to make room for the updated row.